# How to Group the duplicate items in MySQL separately

Tags: mysql

I have a request table..

```
user_id     no:of_mach         time_start                 req_time
11               3             2012-12-12 09:00:00      2012-12-11 09:00:00
12               4             2012-12-14 08:00:00      2012-12-14 06:00:00
13               4             2012-12-12 09:00:00      2012-12-12 02:00:00
14               2             2013-12-12 07:00:00      2012-12-12 03:00:00
15               2             2012 12-14 08:00:00      2012-12-14 05:00:00
```

From the above table, I need to get the req_time of the users who has requested for the same time_start.

The duplicate time_start are

```
2012-12-12 09:00:00 by user_id 11,13.
2012-12-14 08:00:00 by user_id 12,15.
```

Now, each of theirs request time is different.. 
I want a query so that it will get me the result as:-

req_time of user requested for the time_start 2012-12-12 09:00:00 are:-

```
2012-12-11 09:00:00
2012-12-12 02:00:00
```

req_time of user requested for the time_start 2012-12-14 08:00:00 are:-

```
2012-12-14 06:00:00
2012-12-14 05:00:00
```

I have used a query:-

```
SELECT req_time FROM user_req WHERE user_id IN (SELECT o.user_id FROM user_req o INNER JOIN ( SELECT starttime, COUNT( * ) AS dupeCount FROM user_req GROUP BY starttime HAVING COUNT( * ) >1)oc ON o.starttime = oc.starttime) ORDER BY req_time ASC;
```

And this prints all the req_time together for all the duplicate time_start values..

The output will be :-

```
2012-12-11 09:00:00
2012-12-12 02:00:00
2012-12-14 06:00:00
2012-12-14 05:00:00
```

Can I have a query that help me to group this req_time based on each duplicate time_start which I have explained above.
Then I can call it in java and use it for my program..

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from user_req where time_start in
(select time_start
 from user_req
 group by time_start
 having count(time_start) > 1)
 order by time_start, req_time
```

This will return records from the table with multiple counts of same `time_start`, ordered by the `start_time` and `req_time`. You can choose to show only those 2 columns if you want by replacing the `select *` with appropriate column names.

Comment: thank tou for the help... may I know how to modify the above query so that I can get the details of only one time_start=2012-12-14 08:00:00 , so that I can check for the duplicates of the same and get the requested time i.e, req_time also.. please let me know that..

Comment: @:shree.pat18  thank tou for the help... may I know how to modify the above query so that I can get the details of only one time_start=2012-12-14 08:00:00 , so that I can check for the duplicates of the same and get the requested time i.e, req_time also.. please let me know that

Comment: Add a `where` clause to filter by date.

Comment: @sb15 Glad to help! Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped to resolve the issue.